# How do I get the email address of a Firebase user by ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using email/password authentication in Firebase. So every user has an email address. My users are in groups, and I want each user to be able to see all the other users in the group. Specifically, I want to display a list of emails in the frontend to the user. My question is not about how to make rules for that, but rather, **how do I get a user's email addresses given a user ID**? Note that I'm asking about getting a list of *other* users, not the currently signed in user.

I haven't found any SO answers showing how to get the email address of another user via `auth()`. I've seen suggestions to place the email in the `/users` collection under the user ID, but that seems incredible brittle to me to store the email addresses in both `auth()` and `/users/$userId`. Changing email addresses will be a nightmare. So there must be a way to get the emails from `auth()`, right?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason this question should have been downvoted. If there's something wrong with the question, please leave a comment here so that I can edit it to provide more value to Googlers.

Comment: Sorry Kyle. There is no public API to get a list of users from Firebase Authentication. If you'd like to request that the feature be added, chime in [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). Aside from that, I don't see how this question is different from these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+list+of+users, all of which will point to storing the users in a separate database. Brittle or not, that is currently the only known way (which is used by quite a few developers).

Comment: Thanks Frank, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Even though it's a terrible solution, it's better than answering a different question. I'll mark your answer the solution if you update it to make that more clear so that future Googlers don't get confused. Thanks Frank.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think the OP is asking the following question; given that we have users and each user is part of a group of other users, how do I get the email addresses of the *other users* that are in the same group as this user. Feel free to tell me that's a totally wrong interpretation of the OP's question, and I'll go back to my corner :-)

Comment: @jay Well really my question is, "how do I get a user's email address given a user ID?". It's in bold above.

Comment: Huh. Based on your comment to @FrankvanPuffelen answer, you stated *I need to know how a user can get a list of emails*. So it seems like you may have two questions or perhaps we misunderstand. If your question is "how do I get a user's email address given a user ID?", then Franks answer is correct! If not, maybe clarifying the question would help us to help you.

Comment: @Jay Frank's answer does not answer the question. I need to do this without Firebase Admin SDK because I'm doing this in the frontend. I clearly said that in the question. If I had enough rep, I would downvote his answer because it was made clear that that is not what I'm trying to do. The best answer so far is Frank's comment on this question (second comment).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the email address of a specific user, you can use the new Firebase Admin SDK.

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the tables below for the contents of userRecord
    console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  })
```

See [the documentation on retrieving user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).

As its name implies, the Admin SDK runs with elevated authorization and thus should only be run on trusted hardware, e.g. an application server you control.

As I commented: there is no API to get a list of users.

Comment: Admin SDK cannot be run on the client side (in Angular), so this does not answer my question. I need to know how a user can get a list of emails. Whether that's through an SDK, or by storing it in the `/users` collection. I just need some sort of solution.